# Pinpoint where a Javascript being called?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Using either Chrome or Firefox debugger, I can see that a call is made in Network, by a script to

`https://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=jQuery112204764504606409188_xyz&_=xyz1`

However, I cannot find the originating script that's making this cross-site call.

Is there any way to pinpoint that by using just the Chrome or Firefox debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome: F12/Developer - Network (Record) - column "Initiator" (click for details)

Comment: Thanks Julius, any Firefox equivalent?